# How does this code work? How am I getting this output?

Tags: c

I am using c preprocessor directive. I want to know how does this program work?

```
#define PRODUCT(x) (x*x)
   main()
   {
   int i=3,j;
   j=PRODUCT(i+1);
   printf("\n%d",j);
   }
```

The output is

```
7
```

Comment: To avoid UB, you need to `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: `main()` really should be `int main()`, or even better `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#define PRODUCT(x) (x*x)` is actually a macro. It behaves differently from usual C functions.

**Macros are simple text substitutions done before the compiler sees the code.**

Therefore, what actually happens here could be illustrated as:

1. `j = PRODUCT(i+1);`
2. `j = PRODUCT(3+1);`
3. The code then changes to :
   **j = 3+1*3+1;**

   ```
   main(){
     int i = 3,j;
     j = 3+1*3+1;
     printf("\n%d",j);
   }
   ```
4. According to the operator precedence rule, it is evaluated as,

   - `3+(1*3)+1`
   - `3+3+1`
   - `7`

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I get 7 with `PRODUCT(i+1)`?

because `3+1*3+1` == `3+3+1`

---

Try `#define PRODUCT(x) ((x) * (x))`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your code is like this, I presume:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRODUCT(x) x * x


int main(void)
{
   int i=3, j;
   j = PRODUCT(i+1);
   printf("\n%d",j);

   return 0;
}
```

Normally, you think that, it should show 16, as (3 + 1) * (3 + 1) is equal to 16. However, preprocessor does not work like this. It simply changes those defined labels in the code. That is, before compiling, your code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i=3, j;
   j = i + 1 * i + 1;  // in this case, 3 + 1 * 3 + 1 = 3 + 3 + 1 = 7
   printf("\n%d",j);

   return 0;
}
```

If you want to have desired output of 16, declare it in a right way:

`#define PRODUCT(x) ((x) * (x))  // put as many braces as you can`

In this case, your code, before compiling will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int i=3, j;
   j = ((i + 1) * (i + 1));  // in this case, (3 + 1) * (3 + 1) = 16
   printf("\n%d",j);

   return 0;
}
```

If you want to know more about macros, check this link: [macros in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-facts-preprocessors-c/)

Comment: I'd add another set of parentheses around all of the macro expansion :)